# How will you split a full name when his/her name consisting of 2 or more words from his/her last name in "PANDAS? Is there an easy way to do it?

Tags: pandas, string, methods, split

[image]

I tried to concatenate the two columns firstname and lastname into one columns. Now, how about to split it into two columns when his/her firstname consisting of 2, 3 and more words from his/her lastname? Is there any easy way to do it? I tried using str.split() methods. But it says "columns should be the same length."

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `str.extract` here:

```py
df[["firstname", "lastname"]] = df["fullname"].str.extract(r'^(\w+(?: \w+)*) (\w+)$')
```

The regex pattern used above assigns as many name words from the start as possible, leaving only the final component for the last name.  Here is a formal explanation of the regex:

- `^` from the start of the name

  - `(` open first capture group `\1`

    - `\w+` match the first word
    - `(?: \w+)*` then match space and another word, together zero or more times
  - `)` close first capture group
  - match a single space
  - `(\w+)` match and capture the last word as the last name in `\2`
- `$` end of the name

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I really appreciated it. I am a beginner in using pandas and I am eager to learn it because I wanted to shift career. By the way, what is the explanation for the (r'^(\w+(?: \w+)*) (\w+)$')? Can you please answer it so that I can understand what's inside of the parenthesis ( ) of the .str.extract method. Thanks!